# .onLoad and interactive - unexpected behaviour?

Tags: r, package, interactive

I have a package which is intended to be used by non-interactive scripts run via Rscript. But I also want to be able to load it up in an interactive session, mostly for debugging purposes. When used in an Rscript or other non-interactive session I want to use .onLoad to do some initialisation, so I have something along the lines of:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    if ( !interactive() ) { 
        # Do some stuff 
    } else {
    # Do something slightly different
}
```

The problem is that even in an interactive session, interactive() is returning FALSE inside .onLoad. I test this via:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    print( paste( "interactive() = ", interactive(), collapse="" ) )
}
```

Then when I `build()` and `install()` (using devtools) the installation attaches the library with the message `"interactive() = FALSE"`.

Any ideas? Neither the documentation for .onLoad() nor for interactive() say anything pertinent.

Phil

Answer (score 2):

After you run `build()` and `install()`, have you tried un-attaching *and* un-loading the package, then reloading it?

Here's what I get when I do that, including your `.onLoad` function in a package called 'dummy':

```
 library(devtools)
 document('dummy')
 build('dummy')
 install('dummy')
 # ...
 # [1] "interactive() =  FALSE"

 detach("package:dummy", unload=T)
 library(dummy)
 # [1] "interactive() =  TRUE"
```

Comment: Strangely `install` didn't seem to attach the package even though it returned with no errors. When I tried loading it via `library` it indeed gave "interactive() = TRUE". Thanks!